# Flask dynamic routing

Tags: python, flask, dynamic-routing

I'm just starting to learn `Flask` but I can't even get through this beginner step. I have tried to make a `dynamic URL` route as below but when I go to http://127.0.0.1:5000/home for example, it says `"NOT FOUND"`. Any help appreciated!

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/") #this is the default domain
def home():
    return "<h1>Hello this main page</h1>"

@app.route("/<name>")
def user(name):
    return f"hi {name}"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Are you certain you're not accessing `http://127.0.0.1:5000/home/` (note the trailing forward slash)?

Comment: See reply to answer below!

Comment: I have the same problem and it is a big headache

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the route /home.
Try this :)

```
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return "<h1>Hello this main page</h1>"
```

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't quite clear: the default homepage is working fine! It's the dynamic URLs that just don't work. Eg going to "http://127.0.0.1:5000/bob" should come up with a page saying "hi bob"

Comment: From my reading of the question, I think OP expected for the dynamic route `/<name>` to work.

Comment: My bad! This should work according to https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules . try the url with `/user/<username>` and the function should then take username as a parameter!

Comment: Unfortunately this still isn't working! The update I made: ```@app.route('/<username>')
def show_user_profile(username):
    # show the user profile for that user
    return username``` still returns Not Found when going to ```http://127.0.0.1:5000/a```

Comment: Figured out an issue! I'm changing the text for the default home page, but it is not updating when I go to ```http://127.0.0.1:5000/```. I assume I'm missing something very simple but I'm saving the script, re-running the server and going to that URL but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You might forget to add a slash after"/home"
It should look like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "HI"

@app.route("/<name>/")
def hello(name):
    return f"Hello, {name}."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```